# Unable to use fetch / any http request in outlook scriptlab

Tags: javascript, outlook, get, fetch-api

I'm trying to make a simple GET request inside an outlook add-in, this request works in postman and it gives me this code:
Fetch

```
var myHeaders = new Headers();
myHeaders.append("Device", "ffbc262f692a075funknown");

var requestOptions = {
  method: 'GET',
  headers: myHeaders,
  redirect: 'follow'
};

fetch("http://******/admin/App?action=getEntryLogs", requestOptions)
  .then(response => response.text())
  .then(result => console.log(result))
  .catch(error => console.log('error', error));
```

JQuery

```
var settings = {
  "url": "http://******/admin/App?action=getEntryLogs",
  "method": "GET",
  "timeout": 0,
  "headers": {
    "Device": "ffbc262f692a075funknown"
  },
};

$.ajax(settings).done(function (response) {
  console.log(response);
});
```

XHR

```
// WARNING: For GET requests, body is set to null by browsers.

var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.withCredentials = true;

xhr.addEventListener("readystatechange", function() {
  if(this.readyState === 4) {
    console.log(this.responseText);
  }
});

xhr.open("GET", "http://******/admin/App?action=getEntryLogs");
xhr.setRequestHeader("Device", "ffbc262f692a075funknown");

xhr.send();
```

I tried this

```
function GetAccesses(event) {
  const responseType = "json";
  var myHeaders = new Headers();
  myHeaders.append("Device", "ffbc262f692a075funknown");

  var requestOptions: RequestInit = {
    method: "GET",
    headers: myHeaders,
    redirect: "manual"
  };
  fetch("http://******/admin/App?action=getEntryLogs", requestOptions)
    .then((response) => response.text())
    .then((result) => console.log(result))
    .catch((error) => console.log("error",error));
}
```

inside of scriptlab, but I just get the error:

> "Type error: unable to fetch"

without anything else, any idea?

This is the data I get back from Postman, I don't get a respond from inside scriptlab:

```json
{
    "data": [
        {
            "result": 10,
            "idAccessServer": 45082,
            "id": 19,
            "idContractServer": 0,
            "idPlant": 3,
            "type": 0,
            "align": 1,
            "idPersonServer": 3523,
            "idServer": 19
        },
        {
            "result": 10,
            "idAccessServer": 45083,
            "id": 20,
            "idContractServer": 0,
            "idPlant": 3,
            "type": 1,
            "align": 1,
            "idPersonServer": 3377,
            "idServer": 20
        }
    ],
    "success": "true"
}
```

This is the error I get in the console:

> TypeError {} message: "Failed to fetch" stack: "TypeError: Failed to fetch at HTMLButtonElement.GetAccesses (script-lab-runner.azureedge.net/:17:5) at HTMLButtonElement.dispatch (unpkg.com/jquery@3.1.1:5201:27) at elemData.handle (unpkg.com/jquery@3.1.1:5009:28)" proto: TypeError constructor: function TypeError() message: "" name: "TypeError" proto: Error constructor: function Error() message: "" name: "Error" toString: function toString() proto: Object, I found this error also

Comment: `For GET requests, body is set to null by browsers` - no issue there, it's a warning, and you aren't sending a body anyway

Comment: Maybe I'm failing at the basics.... I'm not getting a response in the code, nothing at all, only the error

Comment: I don't think I've ever seen *unable to fetch* without another message being logged to the console (as a separate entry). Are you certain there is nothing else?

Comment: TypeError {}
message: "Failed to fetch"
stack: "TypeError: Failed to fetch at HTMLButtonElement.GetAccesses (https://script-lab-runner.azureedge.net/:17:5) at HTMLButtonElement.dispatch (https://unpkg.com/jquery@3.1.1:5201:27) at elemData.handle (https://unpkg.com/jquery@3.1.1:5009:28)"
__proto__: TypeError
constructor: function TypeError()
message: ""
name: "TypeError"
__proto__: Error
constructor: function Error()
message: ""
name: "Error"
toString: function toString()
__proto__: Object, I found this error also

Comment: that's the sort of detail that needs to be **in the question**

Comment: Sorry, found out later....